# Swift GCDAsyncSocket acceptOnPort:Error: not opening a port?

Tags: swift, gcdasyncsocket

I'm using Xcode beta 3 on 10.9 to write a server using GCDAsyncSocket.  The following code returns true and doesn't produce an error, but Network Utility says that port 5050 is not open.

```
var tcpSocket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())

let lPort: UInt16 = 5050;
var listenError : NSError?
let listening = tcpSocket.acceptOnPort(lPort, error: &listenError)
if listenError {
    println("Error opening listen socket \(listenError!.localizedDescription)")
} else {
    println("Opened listen port")
}
```

On the same machine, in the same version of Xcode, the ObjC equivalent runs fine and opens a port on 5050.  Is there a problem with my code, GCDAsyncSocket, Swift or Xcode?

TIA.

Comment: I have same issue. if I provide my custom port the connection will be refused! did you solve it?

Comment: Have you got any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this same problem. As a workaround, specifying the listening port as 0 which lets the OS pick the port to use seems to work for me.